# Icon next to selected menu item with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a menu with ng-repeat where once I select an item, an icon is displayed next to it. The example on angular website does not use ng-repeat therefore I cannot use it https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/demo/menuBar I want the same behavior like when you go to ->View->Mode . Is there any way to make md-menu-content a single selection like a radio group ? I'm trying to make the icon displayed for only one item.  Here is codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmpGxO?editors=1010

```
<md-toolbar class="md-menu-toolbar">
<md-menu-bar>
  <md-menu>
    <button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
          View
        </button>
    <md-menu-content>
      <md-menu-item class="md-indent" ng-repeat="phase in ctrl.phases"  type="checkbox" 
                    ng-model="ctrl.settings[phase.name]">

        <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
        <md-button ng-click="ctrl.sampleAction('redo', $event)">
          {{phase.name}}
        </md-button>

      </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
  </md-menu>
</md-menu-bar>
```

EDIT: it's vital that the icon is displayed on the right hand side like on angular website. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
<md-menu-item class="md-indent" ng-repeat="phase in ctrl.phases"  type="radio" ng-value="phase.name" ng-model="ctrl.settings">
```

[pen](http://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/VbGweG?editors=1010)